# When i try to run a discord bot it says that "message is not defined"

Tags: discord.js

When i try to run the bot it says that "message is not defined" in the string message.author.kick()

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'textstring') {
    message.author.kick();
  }
});
```

It is suposed to kick the sender of the message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`message` is not defined anywhere. You begin the scope using `msg =>` so `msg` is the defined variable for the message object.

Change `message.author.kick();` to `msg.author.kick();`

Comment: @imathinmint Your ability to selfreflect is honorable. But please be careful with your language, even towards yourself. Maybe something like "Oh. I should have seen that myself and will be more thorough in the future."

Comment: The [`kick()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kick) method is for a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), not a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User). Use [`msg.member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member), but you must also check [`msg.guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild) and [`msg.member.kickable`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=kickable) before.